Is it possible to have Webhook as generic component
Let us say I have a set of systems I can integrate with, but it takes long time to implement integrations with all of them. So I build a software to communicate with other apps using Webhook. Where I can receive data from other Systems.
I know from https://webhooks.fyi/ the other systems can can have different security mechanisms to implement their webhooks.
Is it possible to build a Generic webhook I can use to integrate with all systems (which supports webhook), and how should I approach it?

Yes it's possible.
Have you decided which technology's and programming languages your system will be implemented in?  If yes, see what existing libraries and frameworks (etc) you can find for your technologies that will help you.
In terms of architecture, you want to create logical layers in your solution so that the integration is keep separate from the rest of your solution.
Within the integration layer you want to use Dependency Inversion; this is a design principle where you program against a contract/interface rather than "hard-code" against a specific piece of code / class:
[Logic] -- [Contract] -- [Implementation]

Using this approach you'll be able to create a "plug-and-play" architecture where you can create any number of WebHook providers.  For example, you might build a concrete webhook provider per system (that you want to integrate with), and load them dynamically; or you might find you only need to build 2 or 3 slightly different providers and feed them with different parameters at runtime.
Wikipedia provides information on Dependency Inversion and you will find lots of other information & guides if you look online: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle
Designing and implementing a system base on dependency inversion can be a challenge if you have never dine it before - there's lot so of new ideas to get your head around, but the investment you make will be well worth it.  What I mean by this is that you should expect to have to do a fair amount of research and design / prototyping before you make progress, so be mentally prepared for that.
